# How to interpret encryption round diagrams

Tags: encryption

I was thinking about implementing a symmetric cipher - just for the knowledge, no intent to use in my code in production.

I often find diagrams like this:

[image]

(From IDEA cipher wiki page)

I can get each "node" means an operation like XOR, but is there any reference about what each kind of symbol means?

Answer (score 3):

Usually these diagrams come with a text description of the algorithm, usually the formulae that must be evaluated to obtain the cipher text. The diagram is there to illustrate the process. So if you read the text and diagram side-by-side it should be more clear what the various boxes illustrate.

Answer (score 3):

Such diagrams make sense only when part of a specification or description which defines all the diagram elements in full mathematical details. E.g., for IDEA, [this document](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46877-3_35). In this case, the data paths have with 16 bits each (IDEA works on 64-bit blocks), the "+" sign in a circle is bitwise XOR, the "+" in a square is addition (modulo 2<sup>16</sup>), and the dot in a circle is multiplication modulo 2<sup>16</sup>+1 (with the special convention that a 16-bit word containing only zeros really means 2<sup>16</sup>, not 0).

The signs with a "+" (in a circle or a square) are kind of traditional and will be used with such meanings in many specifications (but not all !). However, diagrams are **illustrations**; the real specification consists in the accompanying text.

Answer (score 1):

It is a function block diagram of some sort. I've not been able to find an explicit standard for drawing these diagrams.

This [exercise book](http://www.iem.uni-due.de/~vinck/crypto/problems-crypto.pdf) does introduce/indirectly teach the diagram style in later chapters.